# How to display custom html tag?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to read user input text and display it.

I've tried:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="post.content" />
</div>

<div>
    <div ng-bind-html="post.content| htmlize"></div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
let app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {

    // controller implements...

}).value('HTMLIZE_CONVERSIONS', [

    { expr: /\n+?/g, value: '<br />' },
    { expr: /\[([BUI])\](.+)\[\/\1\]/g, value: '<$1>$2</$1>' }

]).filter('htmlize', function (HTMLIZE_CONVERSIONS) {

    return function (string) {
        return HTMLIZE_CONVERSIONS.reduce(function (result, conversion) {
            return result.replace(conversion.expr, conversion.value);
        }, string || '');

    };
});
```

When I type:

> [B]bold[/B] [U]underline[/U] [I]italic[/I]

it would convert to:

> **bold** u̲n̲d̲e̲r̲l̲i̲n̲e̲ *italic*

My question: how to prevent the code detects other html tags?

I've tried:

Case:

> `<script>alert('')</script>`

Result:

> 

Case:

> `<h1>text</h1>`

Result:

### text

My goal: I just only want to convert `[B][U][I]` to `<b><u><i>` and display them as html tags (as I show), ortherwise; display it as an plain text.

How can I do that?

Comment: What about first replacing <B><U><I> to other sequences like [B] [U] and [I], then removing any left HTML tag and finally replacing [B][U][I] back to <B><U><I>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can

replace `<` with `&lt;`

replace `>` with `&gt;`

to display `<` and `>` in plain text and then replace `[` and `]` characters with `<` and `>` to make them correct HTML tags

Comment: Yes it is : ). But if you want to display user input in your site, remember to make sure that you secure your site against XSS attacks! Here are some good tips:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet